# Getting spring boot project working, no sources were created

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Hi guys I just downloaded intellij idea version 2016.3.1 in mac os x el capitan
and try to create spring boot project. I did everything according to [Creating Spring Boot Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-spring-boot-projects.html) tutorial however I sources are totally different and does not have any resources or default java class.
 Someone had similar problems over here but his solution did not help me [Difficulty Getting Spring Boot Project Working](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207698129-Difficulty-Getting-Spring-Boot-Project-Working)

[image: project structure]

Comment: Use http://start.spring.io/ choose options, download, import Maven project into IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @aaa yeah thats good idea but why my intellij does not create source folders?

Comment: Maybe check your maven settings in IntelliJ. In the maven tool window there is a cog / spanner icon. Click that to get see your settings. Check that your settings.xml file looks ok and that you can download dependencies.

Comment: @WillHumphreys how should my settings.xml look like?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

</settings>

Comment: @WillHumphreys you were right problem was with maven in intellij

Comment: @M.T Glad I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with maven in intellij to fix this  go to
  1. Preferences, Build, Executins, Deployment
  2. Maven
  3. Runner
  under GRE tab specify your JRE path

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help you